# jquery selection of elements with no visible children

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, children, visible

Here's my goal: do something on an element, an `<optgrooup>`, if all of its children are invisible.

My code below outlines the  in red if it has *any* invisible children.  But I want to do so only if *all* the children are invisible.  If the element has any children that are visible, then don't highlight it.

How can I tweak the jQuery selector to do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="availableInstanceId" id="availableInstanceId">
<optgroup label="Option Group 1">
   <option >visible item 1</option>
   <option >visible item 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Option Group 2 - Should be highlighted">
   <option style="display:none;">invisible A</option>
   <option style="display: none">invisible B</option>
</optgroup>

<optgroup label="Option Group 3 - Should not be highlighted">
  <option >visible C</option>
  <option style="display: none">invisible D</option>
</optgroup></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var filterOptions = function(e) {
  // Goal: highlight the <optgroup>'s that have *only* invisible children
  $( '#availableInstanceId > * > *:hidden').parent().css("border","3px solid red");
} 
$(document).ready(function() {
  filterOptions();
});
</script>
```

Screenshot of image here: http://img144.imageshack.us/img144/556/selectexample.gif

Comment: What about comparing the lengths of the arrays between the invisible and the total children?

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you want to exclude elements with no child elements:

```
 $(":has(*):not(:has(:visible))")
```

[Working example.](http://jsbin.com/alepi)

**UPDATE:** This has much better performance than my original answer:

```
$(":hidden").parent().not( $(":visible").parent() )
```

Comment: Actually, there's a faster way to do this with traversal instead of selection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841401/jquery-selection-of-elements-with-no-visible-children/841568#841568

Comment: The working example worked fine for me in FF, but not on IE 8 (on XP) - are there known problems with jQuery and IE8?

Comment: Neither of Jed's answers work in IE8, not because jQuery is broken but because IE8 doesn't hide the options!

Comment: Good catch, Brian. Does it work if you use this?

$("option")
  .filter( function return(){ this.style.display == "none" })
  .parent().not( $(":visible").parent() )

Comment: It doesn't quite work. You have to take it one step further. I've added a community answer with the correct code.

Answer (score 2):

This has much better performance than my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841401/jquery-selection-of-elements-with-no-visible-children/841460#841460):

```
$(":hidden").parent().not( $(":visible").parent() )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about two lines to do it? One to turn it on for every single element, and one to turn it off again for every one with a visible child?

```
$('#availableInstanceId > *').css("border","3px solid red");
$('#availableInstanceId > * > *:visible').parent().css("border","none");
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to [Jed Schmidt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841401/jquery-selection-of-elements-with-no-visible-children/841460#841460). The following code works in IE8.

Note that IE8 does not actually hide the `<option>` elements despite the `display: none` style. Also IE8 doesn't seem to accept `border` styles for `<optgroup>` elements.

Working sample: http://jsbin.com/aquya (Editable via http://jsbin.com/aquya/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Prevent CSS inherits
  $("option").css('backgroundColor', 'white')

  $("option")
    .filter(function(){
      return this.style.display == 'none';
    })
    .parent()
    .not($('option').filter(function(){
      return this.style.display != 'none';
    }).parent())
    .css('backgroundColor', 'blue')
    .css('border', '1px solid red'); //this doesn't work in IE8
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this was great, at least for highlighting

Unfortunately, what I really want to do is *hide* the optgroup, not highlight it.  I should've said that in the original question - I didn't think it would make a difference, since my main concern was the selector - but it turns out that it does make a difference, since as you mentioned before, IE has a bug with hiding select options (and optgroups - see http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1100).  So it looks like I'm out of luck with IE

Comment: If you don't mind the extra work and complication, you could probably fake it by temporarily deleting the elements you want to hide (I'm guessing, IE might not like that either).

Answer (score 1):

// answer to question changing css as desired

```
    if($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari){

        $('optgroup:not(:has(:hidden))').css("border","3px solid red");

    } else {

        $('optgroup:not(:has(:visible))').css("border","3px solid red");

    }
```

// remove empty optgroups example

```
    if($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari){

        $('optgroup:not(:has(:hidden))').remove();

    } else {

        $('optgroup:not(:has(:visible))').remove();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to compare an array of all the :visible vs. :hidden

here is some pseudo code

```
if ($("#element:hidden").length == $("#element:visible").length) {
  // Do  stuff
} ...
```